# Should I keep all sub-packages on a single version in package.json?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

There is a 3rd-party library my project uses that has split its functionality into multiple imported packages so that a project can install just what it needs. In package.json, several entries are present for the different sub-packages, like...

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@lib/dogs": "^1.0.3",
    "@lib/cats": "^1.0.3",
    "@lib/iguanas": "^1.0.3"
    ...lots more of the same...
  }
```

I don't want to spend time thinking about compatibility issues if one of the sub-packages installs a different version# than the others through semver-range-picking or another developer fixing a problem by incrementing the version on just one sub-package. I suspect there is some risk of bugs if the sub-package versions get out of sync, even if the intent of the package maintainers is to respect the meaning of breaking changes in their versioning. It seems simpler to just have all the sub-packages on the same version by default.

Should I try to enforce (or at least promote) that the sub-packages have the same version?

Comment: The point of having sub-package installations is that they're separable because they don't rely on each other. Incrementing the version of one should not break another, especially if the package developer follows the conventions of semver, which dictate that only major versions should have backwards compatibility changes. Using the `^` notation will ensure that can never occur, so what you have is fine.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts But I don't have control over how well the 3rd-party maintainer respects the meaning of versioning re breaking changes, and suspect it will give me less grief in the long run to keep the versions in-sync.

Comment: If your module is used as a dependency on another program, it's extremely uncommon, at least in my professional experience, that the 3rd-party will even touch the source code contained in your module, including `package.json`. However, even given the opportunity to "protect a 3rd-party developer from themselves" I would hesitate to do so as that will tend to create more compatibility issues, not less. If they need to change their sub-dependency versions through other means besides touching your source-code like the new `package-lock.json` functionality in npm, they should be able to do so.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts, I'm starting to see your point, and it may boil down to how much I trust 3rd parties to update their sub-package versions responsibly. If they are reliable, then I should allow the sub-package versions to be out of sync to accommodate things like bugfixes made to just one package. If they aren't reliable, then I may want to micro-manage the version#s. But I should probably start with the first approach, and wait for a problem before going to the second.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm saying, I'm glad you see that. Also, that's what the "Issues" tab on github is for. They can always just ask you directly for the best approach to resolve a compatibility issue, or at least file a bug report for you to check out and fix.

Comment: I revised the question so that it "backs up" and checks my earlier assumption. If you like, feel free to create an answer based on what you've said, and I'll accept it. If you can't be bothered, no worries--I'll sum up an answer after a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Promote, but don't enforce.

Your current set-up, which uses [Caret Ranges](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/semver#caret-ranges-123-025-004) is the default used when installing with the `--save` flag for a reason: it's the most flexible and robust range to use for dependencies that correctly follow the semver conventions. This means that whenever someone `update`'s your module as a dependency to theirs, it will automatically bump their sub-dependencies to the latest version that is backwards-compatible with the one explicitly specified after the `^`.

Because of this, and the fact that [scoped packages](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scope) don't have interdependencies since they behave identically to normal dependencies, leaving identical caret ranges for each of them should already be sufficient enough to avoid compatibility issues by default.

#### Don't protect developers from themselves

A good methodology to follow when considering how to deal with compatibility issues is to avoid the antipattern of "protecting developers from themselves." In this situation, you propose to put a lock in place that prevents 3rd parties from editing the relative versions of your dependencies, to avoid compatibility issues. This is a very vague goal since you haven't actually run into any problems yet, as you've pointed out.

Sometimes, yes, developers might not know what they're doing, in which case they'll probably avoid tampering with your default dependency versions, but sometimes they do know, and it can be frustrating when a developer knows they can resolve a bug and are unnecessarily prevented from doing so. So hold their hand, don't cuff them.

#### npm already chose to avoid this antipattern, you should too.

If a 3rd-party developer chooses to use your module as a dependency, they should have the default amount of freedom available to manage their sub-dependencies through npm by using features like [`package-lock.json`](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package-lock.json), which unlocks a very clean pattern for precisely managing sub-dependency versions without editing the source code of their dependencies.

In conclusion, what you have now is a very clean and flexible approach, following common conventions and not going out of the way to constrain 3rd-party developers.